# React not reading json returned from flask GET endpoint

Tags: python, json, reactjs, flask

I'm trying to fetch data returned from url. Curl to the url results in following:

[{"name": "Hello World!"}]

Following is the code in my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Contacts from './components/contacts';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Contacts contacts={this.state.contacts} />
  )
  }
  state = {
    contacts: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('url')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ contacts: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }

}

export default App;
```

My contact.js contains the following:

```
// src/components/contacts.js

import React from 'react'

const Contacts = ({ contacts }) => {
    return (
    <div>
        <center><h1>Contact List</h1></center>
        {contacts.map((contact) => (
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{contact.name}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    )
};

export default Contacts
```

The data does not get rendered or logged. Is there an issue in the way I'm fetching it?

EDIT: The issue is related to CORS. Not sure why using flask_cors doesn't resolve it. My server looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, request, json
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return json_response([{"name":"Hello World!"}])

def json_response(payload, status=200):
     return (json.dumps(payload), status, {'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: your code looks fine.. are you facing any issue

Comment: data does not get displayed on the webpage. It should show "Hello World"

Comment: i posted your code with different api, you can check that

Comment: can you post the pic of network tab.. the response headers and the preview tab with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this example of your code with dummy api and your code is working fine.

the only thing is different api

```
    class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        contacts: []
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <Contacts contacts={this.state.contacts} />
      )
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://35.222.96.248:5000/`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
        this.setState({ contacts: data });
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  }
    }
    const Contacts = ({ contacts }) => {
        return (
        <div>
            <center><h1>Contact List</h1></center>
            {contacts.map((contact) => (
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{contact.title}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            ))}
        </div>
        )
    };
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-ze5pr)

Comment: I followed the same. This works, but if I change the url to the one I want it doen't work. Is there any issue with the response from my url? I have included it in my post

Comment: @SrishtiRawal there is no problem with your frontend. the problem is in your api, check that

Comment: I used curl to check the response from the api, it seems correct

Comment: @SrishtiRawal i already showed you about your frontend code that your code is fine. you need to debug/test your api from postman or something else

Comment: Postman returns this: [
    {
        "name": "Hello World!"
    }
]

Comment: @SrishtiRawal and what is your url that you are passing inside fetch()?

Comment: @SrishtiRawal ok, the problem is cors. your api is http and UI needs https for secured

Comment: @SrishtiRawal enable your cors from backend(your api) then it will work properly

Comment: @SrishtiRawal check this tutorial https://enable-cors.org/server_flask.html

Comment: CORS does not seem to be a problem, API returns a 200 when hit from UI. And I tried enabling CORS, still doesn't work. I'm not familiar with react, does it always need https?

Comment: @SrishtiRawal check this it's working now... it was cors issue

Comment: It is the CORS issue. I see App.js:18 GET https://35.222.96.248:5000/ net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in my network tab. Where do you see it working? I've added what you suggested to my API but I still see that error

Comment: @SrishtiRawal your http://35.222.96.248:5000/ isn't working... run this first and let me know

Comment: @SrishtiRawal check live demo app now, it's working properly

Comment: @SrishtiRawal please accept/vote for it if answer was helpful for you.

Comment: It does not seem to be working for me. Is there some setting in the browser that's causing this?

Comment: @SrishtiRawal check live demo sandbox in incognito tab